# bind_cols when one data_frame contains list column

Tags: r, dplyr

**Background**

I have a function which takes a `data.frame`, estimates a model and should return the original data fortified by the model.

**What I have so far**

If the input data is already grouped, I rely on `left_join` using the grouping variable as the column to join by. However, if there is *no* grouping, `left_join` won't work as there is no column to join by. I want to avoid to create a dummy variable, as this would mean I have to decide on a column name, which could be already present in the data. Thus, I thought I could rely on `bind_cols`. However, as there are `list` columns in the second `tibble`, `bind_cols` won't work.

**Questions**

1. The whole `if(is.grouped_df(.))` approach feels a bit hackish. Are
   there "better" ways to achieve the same?
2. How can I `bind_cols` when
   the second `data_frame / tibble` contains `list` columns?

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
g <- function(mdat) {
    ## am/mpg hard coded in this toy example
    addDat <- mdat %>%
       do(mod = lm(mpg ~ am, .), data = (.))
    if (is.grouped_df(mdat)) {
       left_join(mdat, addDat, by = group_vars(mdat))
    } else {
       bind_cols(mdat, addDat)
    }
}

g(mtcars) ## does not work
# Error in cbind_all(x) : Argument 2 must be length 1, not 32

g(mtcars %>% group_by(vs)) ## works as expected
```

Comment: How about changing `bind_cols(as_tibble(mtcars), addDat[rep(1, nrow(mtcars)),])`

Comment: Nice one! +1. How would you deal with grouped / ungrouped input? Would you use the `if` clause to do either `left_join` or `bind_cols`?

Comment: One thing I am not sure is that why you need the 'data' stored in a `list` where each row will store the whole data and it seems like storing more than is needed and  it is slow

Comment: Good point. Hmm, in a later step, I want to transform some columns in the data using some stats from the model. If the model is not part of the `data_frame` I would need to perform lookups in my `mutate`. Thinking about it, this may indeed be the better option. Would you mind putting your comment as an answer, I could accept it then.

Comment: I gave it another thought. The `bind_cols / left_join` option makes it easier to refer to the right model in subsequent `mutate` calls and I do not have to construct a complicated lookup structure. Since my models are already in a `tibble`, I get some headache thinking of filtering and extracting the right model from this tibble (even worse in the presence of pre-grouping) vs. simply using the model which is in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the function work, we could replicate the rows in 'addDat'

```
g <- function(mdat) {
    ## am/mpg hard coded in this toy example
    addDat <- mdat %>%
       do(mod = lm(mpg ~ am, .), data = (.))
    if (is.grouped_df(mdat)) {
       left_join(mdat, addDat, by = group_vars(mdat))
    } else {
       bind_cols(as_tibble(mdat), addDat[rep(1, nrow(mdat)),])
    }
}

g(mtcars)
```

NOTE: But, storing the entire dataset as a `list` for each row would be inefficient